# Include javascript variable on a json-ld application

Tags: javascript, json

Please tell me what is wrong on this script. I found it on this page https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/9po7dtg4/ but it not working on my website.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script id="myJSONID" type="application/ld+json"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var myList = [];

function buildMyList() {
    return ["2 items", "3items", "so on"];
}

$("#myJSONID").text(function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Recipe",
        "recipeIngredient": buildMyList()
    });
});

}

</script>
```

The test page is here (you have to view the source)

```
http://www.al-hamdoulillah.com/horaires-prieres/test.html
```

The result should be :

```
<script id="myJSONID" type="application/ld+json">

{"@context":"http://schema.org/",
"@type":"Recipe",
"recipeIngredient":["2 items","3items","so on"]

}</script>
```

But when the page is loaded, myJSONID is still empty :

```
<script id="myJSONID" type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

This is a screenshot of the result in the console :

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo3Ov.jpg)

Comment: It works on your website. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: I edit the post to show you what I need.

Comment: Yes it was present in your test website when I looked earlier. I don't know why you think it is not there.

Comment: Please send me a screenshot of what you see on the console because there is nothing. The recipteIngredient value is not replace by ["2 items","3items","so on"] MyJSONID is empty.

Comment: It's not empty, I can see it.  Here I've pasted the contents of your script tag from your test website: `{"@context":"http://schema.org/","@type":"Recipe","recipeIngredient":["2 items","3items","so on"]}`

Comment: How it is possible ? When I go to my test page and I look the console, there is no difference between the script and the result. I added the screenshot so you can see.

Comment: That is not the screenshot of the console. That is the original page source. Open web developer tools and inspect the page

Comment: Ok, I can see it now, nice ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the DOM with JavaScript will not change the source code of the page. It will only change the in-memory DOM.

Inspecting your page with a DOM Inspector tool (such as the Elements panel in Chrome's Developer Tools) shows that your code does successfully modify the DOM.

Viewing the source shows no changes, which is the expected behaviour.